# Analog film camera not taking multiple pictures

Tags: canon, film, 35mm, battery

I have recently purchased a Canon Sure Shot AF-7 which appears to be in excellent condition. However, when I do not have film in it the shutter, flash etc. works perfectly well but after loading the film the camera does not allow me to take more than 1 picture.
Although after some experimenting I have discovered that I can take 1 picture, take the batteries out, put the batteries back in and then take another picture.
I am unsure if this could be an issue with the batteries as the recommended batteries are AA Ni-cd batteries (not very common anymore) but I am using 2 AA rechargeable batteries.

Any idea what could be giving me this problem?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the film is not automatically advancing as it should. If you are using rechargeable NiCad or Li-Ion batteries, they output a lower nominal voltage than the recommended alkaline batteries. This may or may not be the source of the failure to advance the film.

When you take out and replace the batteries, does the film advance when you put the batteries back in? If not, then you are repeatedly exposing the same frame of film with each exposure. The [manual for the Sure Shot AF-8](https://www.cameramanuals.org/canon_pdf/canon_sureshot_owl_prima_af_8.pdf) mentions on page 22 that if the batteries are replaced after the film is loaded, the user needs to press the shutter button until "1" is displayed in the film counter window.

The film counter window on the top of the camera, just to the left of the shutter button, should move each time the film advances. If it does not move, then the film is not advancing.

Here's a [link to a PDF copy of the Sure Shot AF-7 manual](https://data2.manualslib.com/pdf3/56/5540/553918-canon/sure_shot_af7.pdf?b472a3b2655c5ac80dc02505f92c1e40).

Comment: Interesting, I will try swapping to alkaline batteries and see if that improves anything. As far as I have noticed the film advances fine when the camera actually allows me to take a photo but does not allow me to take another photo after that - like no shutter noise, no flash, nothing - and it acts as if the camera is switched off. Thank you for the manual.